# Loop array and store all results

Tags: arrays, powershell

Admittedly I am not a strong developer but I have done some research and I want to get a solid answer to my problem.  I see Multi-dimensional Arrays but I am not sure if this is the right answer

I have a three part issue.  Database Server, Database, and Units

There are n Units, there are 4 Database Servers, there are n database (1 database per 1 Unit).

So for example:

- Unit1 is on Database Server 4 using Database DB_Unit1
- Unit2 is on Database Server 4 using Database DB_Unit2
- Unit3 is on Database Server 2 using Database Unit3 (Some Databases are not named DB_Unit)
- Unit4 is on Database Server 1 using Database XYZ
- Unit5 is on Database Server 1 using Database DB_Unit5

I assumed I could use an array to store each string for each Agency but I'm not sure how that works.

So I am trying to write a PowerShell script that uses all of these functions

```
$units = ("Unit1","Unit2","Unit3","Unit4","Unit5")
FOREACH ($Unit in Units){
Invoke-Sqlcmd -ServerInstance $DatabaseServer -Database $Database -Query "Select * from tbl1"
}
```

My outcome is that it would Query each Database Server with the assigned database for each Unit.

Any ideas on how this works with an Array or is there a separate way to associate this data?

Comment: I mean, you could do a simple `$SQLResults | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "Database" -Value $Unit` Then you could just filter by `$SQLResults | where {$_.Database -eq 'Unit3'}` for example. Is that what you mean by associate? I will throw up an answer with a full code sample.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this might be more what you are after. It should run `n` times, where `n` is the number of strings in `$Units`. There should be 5 results added to `$SQLResults`.

```
$Units= ("Unit1","Unit2","Unit3","Unit4","Unit5")
$SQLResults = New-Object System.Collections.ArrayList

ForEach ($Unit in $Units){
    switch ($Unit) {
        "Unit1" { $DatabaseServer = "Database Server 4";$Database = "DB_Unit1" }
        "Unit2" { $DatabaseServer = "Database Server 4";$Database = "DB_Unit2" }
        "Unit3" { $DatabaseServer = "Database Server 2";$Database = "Unit3" }
        "Unit4" { $DatabaseServer = "Database Server 1";$Database = "XYZ" }
        "Unit5" { $DatabaseServer = "Database Server 1";$Database = "DB_Unit5" }
    }
    $UnitResults = Invoke-Sqlcmd -ServerInstance $DatabaseServer -Database $Database -Query "Select * from tbl1"
    $UnitResults | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "Unit" -Value $Unit
    $SQLResults.Add($UnitResults)
}
```

You should then be able to get the specific unit results by doing `$SQLResults | where {$_.Unit -eq "Unit1"}`